# how to detect browser supports HTML5 microdata API

Tags: javascript, html, semantics, microdata

I use the following code to check for HTML5 microdata API support

```
function supports_microdata_api() {
  return !!document.getItems;
}
```

but this is not working properly. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please define "not working properly". It gives an error or what?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr), so you can test it like this:

```
if (Modernizr.microdata) {
  // Yay, microdata is supported!
}
```

Nonetheless [Chrome](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/b54nW_mGSVU/87CLF5jmPdoJ) and [Safari](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/153772) don't seem to support this semantic syntax anymore.